# Using a reed switch with safety in failure

Tags: arduino, reed-switch

I'm planning on building something similar to this project to be used as an alarm for when a stair gate is forgotten open.

[image: Arduino UNO with Reed switch and LCD Display]

Image above taken from this link:
https://www.electronicshub.org/arduino-based-door-monitoring-system/

I have a question about the reed switch.

Using a reed switch seems like a good idea. But I want to make sure that my circuit is protected against possible failure of the reed switch. So I was thinking, should I go for a normally closed one instead? This way, if the reed switch fails or the wiring gets detached, the alarm will trigger.

Is my thinking correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the schematic you intend to use. Don't say "something similar" and then expect us to go to some random web site.

Comment: `if the reed switch fails or the wiring gets detached` this does not make sense if you are using a normally closed reed switch, because the reed switch would be open when the gate is closed

Comment: use a normally open reed switch that has a resistor in parallel ... when the gate is closed, then the resistance of the circuit is very low ... when the gate is open, then the resistance is about the same as the resistor ... when the wire breaks, then the resistance is very high .... this does not detect broken, shorted wires ... add a resistor in series with the reed switch for that

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Apologies.  I've now added the image.

Comment: I think @jsotola has a good idea. You can use an analog input on the Arduino to sense the voltage levels corresponding to different conditions.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks so much for your feedback.  I see what you mean.  I think I didn't think it through before.  A question on the wire breaking: If the wire connecting the reed switch to the Arduino OR the reed switch to ground break then that means that the resistance will be as if the gate is open, correct?  So having a normally open one means that it will be protected against failure of the switch or a disconnected wire, right?  You were saying to add a resistor in series to the switch for that but I don't understand why this helps.

Comment: @the_new_mr connect a switch to a pair of long wires ... measure the resistance at the end of the wires ... what readings do you get for the two switch states? ... now, short the wires ... what reading do you get? ... now, add a series resistor at the switch and repeat the readings

Comment: @jsotola Ok thanks.  Will try this.